# Dense Rank groups

Tags: sql-server, lag, dense-rank

I have a set of data. I want to produce the last field -> D_Rank

```
date  physician  action  D_Rank
2016-01-01  Dr.John  visit  1
2016-01-01  Dr.John  Call   1
2016-01-02  Dr.John  Call   1
2016-01-03  Dr.Jane  Call   2
2016-01-04  Dr.Jane  Call   2
2016-01-05  Dr.Jane  Visit  2
2016-01-06  Dr.John  NoCall 3
2016-01-07  Dr.John  NoCall 3
2016-01-08  Dr.John  Visit  3
2016-01-08  Dr.Jane  Visit  4
2016-01-08  Dr.Jane  Call   4
2016-01-08  Dr.Joe   Visit  5
2016-01-09  Dr.Joe   Call   5
```

Thanks so much in advanced.

Comment: what is your criteria for ranking? like order by day, then doctor's name and then action etc?

Comment: Only date and physician. Action is not important for the ranking.

Comment: Why would the line `2016-01-02  Dr.John  Call   1` get a rank of 1 when it has a different date? Is that a typo?

Comment: Main ranking is Physician. data is sorted by date.

Comment: @KOMAEI What about when you have more than two physicians on  consecutive days?

Comment: @SqlZim we have only two physicans in the same date.

Comment: What about when you have 2 physicians on consecutive days?

Comment: @SqlZim yes. we can have two physicians on consecutive days

Comment: And what rank increments happen then?

Comment: @SqlZim rank only changes by physician change.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't using `dense_rank()`, but in SQL Server 2012+ you can use the `lag()` window function to determine when the `physician` changes, assign that a value and sum it with another window function like so:

```
select date, physician, action
  , change = sum(change) over (order by date, physician desc)
from (
  select *
    , change = case when physician = lag(t.physician) over (order by t.date, t.physician desc) then 0 else 1 end
  from t
  ) s
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/MQDS34484

returns:

```
+------------+-----------+--------+--------+
|    date    | physician | action | change |
+------------+-----------+--------+--------+
| 2016-01-01 | Dr.John   | Visit  |      1 |
| 2016-01-01 | Dr.John   | Call   |      1 |
| 2016-01-02 | Dr.John   | Call   |      1 |
| 2016-01-03 | Dr.Jane   | Call   |      2 |
| 2016-01-04 | Dr.Jane   | Call   |      2 |
| 2016-01-05 | Dr.Jane   | Visit  |      2 |
| 2016-01-06 | Dr.John   | NoCall |      3 |
| 2016-01-07 | Dr.John   | NoCall |      3 |
| 2016-01-08 | Dr.John   | Visit  |      3 |
| 2016-01-08 | Dr.Jane   | Call   |      4 |
| 2016-01-08 | Dr.Jane   | Visit  |      4 |
| 2016-01-09 | Dr.John   | Visit  |      5 |
| 2016-01-09 | Dr.Jane   | Call   |      6 |
| 2016-01-09 | Dr.Jane   | Visit  |      6 |
+------------+-----------+--------+--------+
```

Expanded sample data for another day with muliple physicians.

Comment: We might have two physicians in one date. In this case, this code does not work! Suppose Dr.John has a record in 2016-01-08???

Comment: @KOMAEI Why don't you update your question with that and show what result you would be looking for?

Comment: Sure. I did change the data set.